# How Python assign multiple variables at one line works?

Tags: python

What are the steps that Python actually does to assign multiple variables at one line?

I use to do A[0], A[1] = A[1], A[0] to swap, but recently I got a bug when assigning a linked list.

```
# insert self->node->...
def insert_next(self, node): 
  node.next, node.prev = self.next, self
  self.next, self.next.prev = node, node
```

`self.next` become `node` earlier than I expected, so the assign become

```
self.next, node.next = node, node
```

However, if I do

```
self.next.prev, self.next = node, node
```

It works!

I "assume" the steps are

```
1. cache values at the right side
2. assign to left side one by one, left to right
```

not

```
1. cache values at the right side
2. cache the ref at the left side
2. assign to ref one by one, left to right
```

So, what are the steps?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's something called "expansion assignment" in Python.

Long story short, you can expand an iterable with assignment. For example, this code evaluates and expands the right side, which is actually a tuple, and assigns it to the left side:

```
a, b = 3, 5
```

Or

```
tup = (3, 5)
a, b = tup
```

This means in Python you can exchange two variables with one line:

```
a, b = b, a
```

It evaluates the right side, creates a tuple `(b, a)`, then expands the tuple and assigns to the left side.

There's a special rule that **if any of the left-hand-side variables "overlap", the assignment goes left-to-right**.

```
i = 0
l = [1, 3, 5, 7]
i, l[i] = 2, 0  # l == [1, 3, 0, 7] instead of [0, 3, 5, 7]
```

So in your code,

```
node.next, node.prev = self.next, self
```

This assignment is parallel, as `node.next` and `node.prev` don't "overlap". But for the next line:

```
self.next, self.next.prev = node, node
```

As `self.next.prev` depends on `self.next`, they "overlap", thus `self.next` is assigned first.

Comment: This is a good thing to learn. Do you have links to documents so I can dig deeper?

Comment: @iBug This is gold. I should be able to give you gold.