# why do I have to retrieve variable from function

Tags: python

```
def getperson():
    name = "rachel"
    age = 19
    country = "US"
    return name,age,country

name,age,country = getperson()
print(name)
print(age)
print(country)
```

So I get that making the variables and returning them are the way to return multiple variables, but what is the

```
name,age,country = getperson()
```

for? I get it retrieves it from getperson() function but I don't understand how, why do you have to set those variables equal to the function? can anyone break it down and explain it to me? I feel it is very simple but I still do not understand.

Comment: It's just how the Python (and a whole lot of other languages) syntax works. If you understand that `"it retrieves it from getperson() function"` you are on the right track. Just to make it clear, the names don't have to match the names inside the function, `a, b, c= getperson()` works just as good

Comment: `getperson` is the function. `getperson()` is the result of the function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Python assign multiple variables at one line works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143328/how-python-assign-multiple-variables-at-one-line-works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return name,age,country` mean `getperson()` return a `tuple` that holds those 3 values.

In `name,age,country = getperson()` you are unpacking the `tuple` to 3 variables, each one holds one value in the same order. `name` has the value of `"rachel"`, `age` is 19 ans so on.

```
print(name) # rachel
print(age) # 19
print(country) # US
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show on your question, you declare three variables that is in use of the **getperson()** function **only**.

However, when you return multiple variables after using them in function, it will return it as tuple.

So if you run this :

```py
def getperson():
    name = "rachel"
    age = 19
    country = "US"
    return name,age,country

print(getperson())
```

Your output will be:

```
('rachel', 19, 'US')
```

There is a special option that you can create multiple variables in single line, like this:

```py
name,age,country = getperson()
```

Now what you did is assigning **new variables** called name,age,country and you equaled them to what **getperson()** returns.(tuple created from name,age,country)

Therefore, you can use **name,age,country** now in your rest of the code as variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the getperson() function, all the variables that are created are local to that function. If you create inside a variable called last_name, and try to access it from out of the function, it will give an error, because that variable can only be used locally inside getperson().

That's why you need to send the variables throw what is called "reference". Since you are using the same name for the variables (both in and out of the getperson() function), that's probably confusing you. Here is a similar example to yours:

```
def getperson():
    param1= "rachel"
    param2 = 19
    param3 = "US"
    return param1, param2, param3

name, age, country = getperson()
print(name)
print(age)
print(country)
```

So, what you are doing is getting by reference the values that the function is return. In this case, the first value returned (param1) is assigned to the first equaled to the function (name), the second (param2) with the second (age), and the third (param3) with the third (country).

As you can see, it doesn't matter what name the variable has, because it is going to be assigned in the order you place them (this only works for immutable variables (int, float, string, etc.) with mutable variables, like lists is different).

I hope this helped you :)