# how the left side of the code assign values to counts and bin_edges ?? can anyone please explain this code briefly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I want to know how count and `bin_edges` values are assigned at a time by the `np.histogram`.

```
counts,bin_edges=np.histogram(iris_setosa['sepal_length'],bins=10,density=True)
```

Comment: Is your question about how `np.histogram` works, or about the assignment to its output to the two variables?  The assignment is just a case of Python 'unpacking'.

Comment: can you answer both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing `data` is a 1D numpy array and `bins` is a strict positive integer, the code roughly works like:

```py
import numpy as np

def numpy_histogram(data, bins=10, density=False):
    xmin = data.min()
    xmax = data.max()
    bin_edges = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, bins + 1)
    counts = np.zeros(bins, dtype=int)
    bin_indices = ((data - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) * bins * 0.999999).astype(int)
    for i in bin_indices:
        counts[i] += 1
    if density:
        counts = counts / sum(counts) / (bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0])
    return counts, bin_edges

counts, bin_edges = numpy_histogram(np.random.uniform(1, 10, 20), density=True)
print(sum(counts), counts)
```

So, the min and max of the data are used to define the bin boundaries. (There is one more boundary than there are bins).  Then from each data value `xmin` is subtracted, and divided by the total range of the data. Then multiplied by the number of bins. This identifies the index of the bin where this value should go.  A correction by a factor slightly smaller than 1 is needes so the rightmost value doesn't fall in the following (undefined) bin.

When `density=True`, the counts are normalized such that the sum of the areas of all bars would be one.  The bars have a width of the difference between two successive `bin_edges`.

PS: About Python's assignment of multiple elements simultaneously, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143328/how-python-assign-multiple-variables-at-one-line-works) is interesting.

Comment: thanks a lot <3 i don't get the whole concept now because i am beginner but i get the answer of my question how it returns two values from same function