# What does this line mean? xU, xL = x + 0.5, x - 0.5

Tags: python, numpy

I came across this code but I couldnt understand what this syntax xU, xL mean. What is it called in python?

xU, xL = x + 0.5, x - 0.5

See the full code bellow:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 11)
xU, xL = x + 0.5, x - 0.5 
prob = ss.norm.cdf(xU, scale = 3) - ss.norm.cdf(xL, scale = 3)
prob = prob / prob.sum() # normalize the probabilities so their sum is 1
nums = np.random.choice(x, size = 10000, p = prob)
plt.hist(nums, bins = len(x))
```

Comment: Have you considered printing out the variables involved?

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52143328/10217732) what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can assign values to multiple variables at once.
Eg:

```
x, y = 5, 6
```

This means that

```
x = 5
y = 6
```

Therefore the statement

```
xU, xL = x + 0.5, x - 0.5
```

means:

```
xU = x + 0.5
xL = x - 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the same as if you had the two lines below:

```
xU = x + 0.5 
xL = x - 0.5
```

when you have a tuple of variables that you assign another tuple to, every value in the second tuple is assigned to its corresponding variable in the first tuple. For more information see this [link](https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/) or you can google "python tuple assignmet".